# How can I index our internal source code?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, visual-sourcesafe, code-search-engine

Google Code Search has indexed Subversion and Mercurial repositories, so people can search open source projects. How can I do the same for my company's repository with the least effort and without publishing our code?

We have Trac (with Subversion) at our shop, but it only indexes Changesets, and we also have Visual Source Safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google turned up [VoilaSVN](http://arcetis.voilasvn.com/main/EN/products.html) but I cannot vouch for it.

Edit: It also turned up [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) which appears to have a lot more support for other systems.

Comment: VoilaSVN free edition is free of charge for commercial and non-commercial usage.
It is a Subversion search engine, administration, online diff and history navigation solution.
It aims to promote the adoption of Subversion® for IT and NON-IT users with its very user-friendly interface.

Comment: The link for VoilaSVN is stale. Looks like the project moved to SourceForge http://voilasvn.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8):

I can vouch for the usefulness of [opengrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/), we have it at work and I use it pretty well every day.

Comment: I can vouch for opengrok as well. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

there's always lxr (linux cross reference).  [Mozilla](http://mxr.mozilla.org) uses

It'd take a lot of effort, I think, because it's only available via git repo.  More power to you if you make it work.  git://lxr.linux.no/git/lxrng.git

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I've found that the built-in search capability of Vista are very helpful. I've just added my source tree to the indexed directories, and get quite fast indexed search.

It is not language-sensitive, however.

Answer (score 1):

Our langauge-sensitive source code search engine can be found
at [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine).   It can handle many languages at the same time.
Searches can be performed for patterns in a specific langauge,
or patterns across languages (such as "find identifiers involving TAX").
By being sensitive to langauge tokens, the number of false positives is reduced,
saving time for the user.  It understands C, C++, C#, COBOL, Java, ECMAScript, Java, XML, Verilog, VHDL, and a number of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Commercially, there's [Krugle Enterprise](http://www.krugle.com/products/).  If you want to see how it works, you can use http://www.krugle.org/ to search open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

for Local Source code search on Windows: CodeIDX works great!
https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeidx/

I Know this question is not for local search, but this is the only question about source code search tools not marked as "off topic" that I could find