# How to quickly search a subversion repository?

Tags: svn, lucene.net, code-search-engine

We are looking at writing a site using Lucene.Net to search our Subversion repository but before we do that has anybody else already tackled this problem?  Something like google for our private source code would be great.

Comment: A similar question was asked recently: [How can I index our internal source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960348?sort=oldest). The answers contain some good alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a source code search software and there are many out on the Internet like

I recommend you [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) by Sun really cool interface and it's opensource and [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye) which in my opinion is the best but has a commercial license