# C# sourcecode Search

Tags: c#, search

I must find a way to research in large number of c# files. Someone knows engine like google code search ready to use and working with c# sorcecode? I find only: http://code.google.com/p/cs2project/  but I'm looking for something more advanced.

Comment: Can you tell us bit more about what your really want to do? Looks like you are looking for open source software, which should have advanced features, should be ready to use, should be able to process large number of files, ... Quite strong requirements!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to [How can I index our internal source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960348/how-can-i-index-our-internal-source-code).