# How can I index my source code?

Tags: full-text-search

Are there any tools out there that will index source code, client side, and provide blazing fast search results?

[How can I index our internal source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960348/how-can-i-index-our-internal-source-code) is related but covers server side tools.

Comment: Client-side is rather wide. Any OS search indexing for any operating system, as well as any replacement for it (like locate32 for windows) will do this. Also, what kind of searching? Does it have to be syntax aware? Regexp? And what OS? What system?

Comment: How could ReSharper possible help you with that?, if you have many projects and so on, multiple solutions, then ReSharper is of no use here.

Comment: How do you expect to see code sitting on the client, if it is well protected?  If you have code intended to be sent to a client, sitting in your source code base, you only need server-side tools.

Answer (score 3):

[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) and [Locate32](http://www.locate32.net/) are nice indexing-tools on the windows platform. Just one problem, they only index the file-names.
[DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) is another solution, it tries to index the content of the files, but have big memory issues as it cannot index the content of bigger files, and just skips them

I'm also on the search for something to index my data, and i want some tool like locate32 wich is supernice to integrate with the windows shell, but it would be nice to get it to index the content of files also, only brute word indexing, no magic to be done to the data, but let me do plain wildcard searches, like words starting with, ending with, and containing.
But the search is still on.. (for an app, that is..)

Answer (score 2):

Install `ctags`.

Then `ctags -R` in the root of your source tree. Many editors, including Vim, can use the resulting `tags` file to give near-instant search results.

Comment: ctags looked interresting, UltraEdit supports it somehow, but ctags did not index my .sql files, I guess there are an option somewhere..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else.

Take a look at CodeIDX: http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeidx/.

Using CodeIDX you can index multiple directories using filetype filters and search the created index.
You can open multiple searches at the same time and the results can be viewed in a preview.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) you can get browsable, searchable source code.  You can run this locally too or use all the tools that go with it (like less to go straight to a function definition).

See http://www.tamacom.com/tour/kernel/linux/ for an example of the Linux Kernel.